# Is there a "next" type of function in Julia, as in Python?

Tags: julia

Is there something comparable to Python's "next" for going through a Julia iterable? I can't seem to find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Python `next()` is `iterate()` in Julia from what I'm seeing

Comment: https://erik-engheim.medium.com/generators-and-iterators-in-julia-and-python-6c9ace18fa93

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/

```
next = iterate(iter)
(i, state) = next
```

Alternatively, it appears `peek` will get the first element, but won't iterate.

Comment: Except for the first iteration, you must supply the state as a second input: `(i, state) = iterate(iter, state)`. Iterators don't normally carry state in Julia, so a plain `next(iter)` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the closest you can achieve, using [`Stateful`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.Stateful) from `Base.Iterators` module:

**Julia**

```
julia> it = Iterators.Stateful((1, 2));
julia> popfirst!(it)
1
julia> popfirst!(it)
2
julia> popfirst!(it)
ERROR: EOFError: read end of file
Stacktrace:
 [1] popfirst!(s::Base.Iterators.Stateful{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Any})
   @ Base.Iterators ./iterators.jl:1355
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[5]:1
```

**Python**

```py
>>> it = iter((1, 2))
>>> next(it)
1
>>> next(it)
2
>>> next(it)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Comment: This is the most correct answers, just 1 thing: you can just use `first`, there's no need to use `popfirst!`.